# Best way to store data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am developing a project where there are lots of relations are there. I want to know which one is best method to store data.

1. create child_model and then push _id to parent_model.
2. create child_model inside parent model, we are pushing whole data not just _id.

Comment: The truth is that there is no "best way". There is only really the one that is "best" for how your application uses the data. The basic distinction is based on whether or not you mostly read both parent and child data together all of the time, and to some extent update that way as well. Or on the other hand where seperation of parent and child is important, either by the sheer number of children or possibly even where update concurency of those child entries is really important to you. Without a really detailed and specific use case, it's really not a one or the other answer.

Comment: I'd like DDD aproach. Separate domain entities in different collections. But value objects must be part of entity in one document. It's works, cause most time you need to read full entity. It's not a straight rule, of course

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best way", both are sometimes the best. It really depends on your use case and questions like these:

- do you need to  load or store your children sometimes separately without loading your parent? -> separate models.
- or will you need to load the parent anyway all the time when you need a child? -> same model
- can your child always only belong to exactly one parent? -> same model
- will multiple parents or other objects ever reference a child? -> separate models
- is the lifetime of your child always identical to the lifetime of your parent -> same model
- can the lifetimes be different? can your child ever become "detached" from your parent -> separate models.

think about those questions and decide, whats best for your use case.